# Neon animation doesn't work on a div inside a paper-dialog

Tags: jquery, html, animation, polymer, neon-animation

I want to show a `<paper-dialog>` and then if I press the `<button>` inside my `<div>`, which is here a red rectangle would go up and down inside my `<paper-dialog>` like it is scanning something. So here's the code of how I create them :

```
<paper-button raised onclick="dialog.open()">plain dialog</paper-button>

<paper-dialog id="dialog">
      <div id="rect" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red"></div>
      <h1>essai</h1>
      <h1>essai</h1>
      <button on-tap="move" raised>Move above rectangle</button>
      <h1>essai</h1>
      <div id="fin">fin</div>
</paper-dialog>
```

But the animation doesn't work at all, here's the code for my script :

```
is: 'my-qrcodescanner',

    behaviors: [
        Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
    ],

    property: {

        animationConfig: {
          value: function () {
            return {
                'move': [{
                    name: 'slide-down-animation',
                    node: this.$.rect
                }, {
                    name: 'slide-up-animation',
                    node: this.$.rect,
                    timing: {delay: 100}
                }]
            }
          }
        }
    },

    move: function () {
        this.playAnimation('move');
    }
```

I don't see my mistake, my imports are good I checked that and I even tried to create a custom element `<my-animatable>` with the script for the animation and then use with a style as a red rectangle but it didn't work either.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/3Xwfh8wG)'s my full code if needed.

The style is messy for now, I will improve it later I just want the animation to work when the button is clicked.

Comment: it's not property but properties. Could it be the reason? because animation 'move' is invalid then

Comment: That was it, didn't saw my mistake, I feel kind of stupid now..
But thanks a lot !

Comment: I added answer so future users will know. Many people wont open question without answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in declaration of properties of custom element. It's not `property` but `properties`.

This can happen to everyone and for beginners it's hard to recognise this mistake. Since you don't have feedback from `Polymer` or `neon-animation` about undefined animation